# Changing axis units of MATLAB spectrogram

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, spectrogram

How can the axis units of the figure generated by `spectrogram` forced to be always "s" (seconds) for the x-axis and "Hz" (Hertz) for the y-axis?

The following spectrogram may serve as a demonstrator. In this example, they have been auto-adjusted by MATLAB to "mins" and "kHz".

```
t = 0:0.0001:200;
x = chirp(t,100,1,200,'quadratic');
spectrogram(x,128,120,128,2e3,'yaxis')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spectrogram` function calls `pspectrogram` to do the actual work, and this in turn calls `engunits` to determine the "engineering units" appropriate for your signal. Apparently `spectrogram`  doesn't have an input option to avoid the unit conversion.

Therefore, the best way seems to be to get the actual outputs of `spectrogram` and plot the image yourself, without unit conversion:

```
[~,F,T,P] = spectrogram(x,128,120,128,2e3,'yaxis');
imagesc(T, F, 10*log10(P+eps)) % add eps like pspectrogram does
axis xy
ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')
xlabel('Time (s)')
h = colorbar;
h.Label.String = 'Power/frequency (dB/Hz)';
```

- Image generated by the **original code**:

  [image]
- Image obtained with the **code above**:

  [image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.